# Convert string to double datatype of gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am data binding of gridview by code behind :

```
protected void PumpGridBind()
 {
    string name = Request.QueryString[1].ToString();
    string query = "select q1.ID  ,  q1.Scenario, q1.Type, q1.StationName ,q1.minH, 
    q1.maxH ,q1.Station_Id, q1.Min_OL, q1.Max_OL, q2.Daily_Abstraction as Action 
    from     
    (select SD.id,SD.Scenario,PR.Type,PR.StationName,max(if(PARAM = 'minH', Value, '
    -999.00')) 
    as 'minH',max(if(PARAM = 'maxH', Value, ' -999.00'))    
    as 'maxH',psd.Station_Id,psd.Min_OL,psd.Max_OL from sgwebdb.param_reference as PR 
    Inner
    join 
    sgwebdb.scenario_data as SD ON PR.Param_Id = SD.Param_Id INNER JOIN 
    sgwebdb.qualicision_detail as Q ON SD.SCENARIO = Q.Alternative INNER JOIN 
    sgwebdb.pump_station_detail as psd ON psd.Station_Id = PR.Station_Id where  PR.Type 
    = 'Pump' and Q.Alternative = '" + name + "' GROUP BY PR.Id) q1 JOIN (SELECT  
    t1.Daily_Abstraction ,t1.Station_id  FROM sgwebdb.pump_station_data t1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
    Station_id, MAX(lastupdate) as lastupdate FROM sgwebdb.pump_station_data  GROUP BY 
    Station_id ) t2 ON t1.Station_id = t2.Station_id AND t1.lastupdate = t2.lastupdate) 
    q2 on
    q1.Station_Id=q2.Station_Id";

    this.GridView2.DataSource = PSI.DataAccess.Database.DatabaseManager.GetConnection
    ().GetData(query);
    GridView2.DataBind();

  }
```

Here gridview's column minH is coming as a string.
Can we convert string to Double before binding with gridview?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
string query = "select q1.ID  ,  q1.Scenario, q1.Type, q1.StationName ,**CAST(q1.minH as DECIMAL(9,2)) q1.minH**
```

Comment: Solutions-MSTeam is this correct syntax CAST(q1.minH as DECIMAL(9,2)) q1.minH